# I want to perform a Redux action based on previous state when my React component mounts and unmounts but the state isn't updating on unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component that has a useEffect I want to trigger only when the component mounts and unmounts

```
    function SomeComponent({ symbol = "BLUE" }) {
      const { syncedState, setSyncedState } = useSyncedStore("Test");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setSyncedState({ symbols: increment({ ...syncedState.symbols }, symbol) });
        return () => {
          setSyncedState({ symbols: decrement({ ...syncedState.symbols }, symbol) });
        };
      }, []);
    }
```

Here `useSyncedStore` is just a custom hook that abstracts some redux logic (I posted a snippet at the end). Basically when the component mounts, the Redux state should increment the state property of the passed in `symbol` prop by 1, and when it unmounts it should decrement it by 1. This component is repeated several times in my React app so if I have 5 of these mounted, my Redux state should show `{BLUE: 5}`. Similarly as I unmount 2 of these components, the Redux state should show `{BLUE: 3}`.

I have the mount/unmount logic handled in my `useEffect` hook but it seems like the `syncedState` is only set when the component first renders I think because nothing triggers a rerender. So lets say I have 3 copies of this `Test` component and it renders like so

| Component Number | Redux State on Render |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `syncedState = {"BLUE": 1}` |
| 2 | `syncedState = {"BLUE": 2}` |
| 3 | `syncedState = {"BLUE": 3}` |

Now the current Redux state is `{"BLUE": 3}`. If I trigger an unmount of the first rendered Test Component 1, it trigger the useEffect cleanup and uses the "current state" it recognizes as `{"BLUE": 1}`, decrements it by one, and saves it to the Redux store. So now the Redux state incorrectly has
`{"BLUE": 0}` when it should be `{"BLUE": 2}`.

How can I ensure the `syncedState` used is up to date with what is actually in the Redux store? I am assuming it has to do with useEffect dependencies but when I add `syncedState` as a dependency it causes an infinite render loop. Any suggestions on what I could look into? Thanks!

```
    // Redux Slice
    const syncedStoreSlice = createSlice({
      name: "syncedStore",
      initialState: initialState,
      reducers: {
        updateSyncedStore: (state, action) => {
          const { name, newState } = action.payload;
          state[name] = { ...state[name], ...newState };
        },
      },
    });

    // Custom Hook that connects to Redux store used by several components
    function useSyncedStore(widgetName) {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const syncedState = useSelector((state) => state.syncedStore[widgetName]) ?? {};

      const setSyncedState = (val) => {
        dispatch(updateSyncedStore({widgetName, val}));
      };

      return { syncedState, setSyncedState };
    }

    // Increments dictionary value by 1
    export const addSymbolToMap = (map, symbol) => {
      if (map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
        map[symbol]++;
      } else {
        map[symbol] = 1;
      }
      return map;
    };


    // Decrements dictionary value by 1
    export const removeSymbolFromMap = (map, symbol) => {
      if (map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
        map[symbol]--;
        if (map[symbol] <= 0) {
          // delete map[symbol];
        }
      }
      return map;
    };
```

Comment: Is your problem similar to [latest store state](https://github.com/sanjar-notes/reactjs-notes/issues/33) (of course, in your case the callback is in useEffect instead of being a custom one)?

Comment: @sanjarcode, yes I believe it is similar! It looks like `submitHandler` performs a Redux state change through dispatch that is not being reflected in the rest of the function. I'm not sure I follow the workaround used though and how it could be applied to my scenario